# How to check for a change in the Inner Text of an html

Tags: selenium-webdriver, c#

I have to check if a change was done in the inner text of an area on my website.

Lets assume this to be the html of such page:

```
<span _ngcontent-c1="" class="image">
   <span _ngcontent-c1="" style="font-weight: 700">test</span>
        "Question"
   <sup _ngcontent-c1="" class="supR">®</sup></span>
```

I have this to find the element:

```
IWebElement testText= driver.FindElement(By.Class("image")).Text;
```

After clicking on an item in the page, the inner text "Question" changes to "Answer", for example.

What is the best way to check the change? Create a new IWebElement and compare it (with an assertion) to the first one? This is the only way I know. Although, I would like to know if there is a better way. Because in case the inner Text changes with other actions, I don't think creating a new IWebElement every time to check if the change was made.

Answer (score 1):

```
IWebElement element = driver.FindElement(By.Id("element-id"));

WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.TextToBePresentInElement(element, "text"));
```

use webdriver wait :https://www.lambdatest.com/blog/explicit-fluent-wait-in-selenium-c/

https://riptutorial.com/selenium-webdriver/example/15496/different-types-of-explicit-wait-conditions

Comment: Thank you. I had a look at those articles before (or similar). My question is still, what if the change is done by an action, like clicking on an item on a page that will make the "Inner text" change? and after, how can i compare the 2 inner texts?

Comment: click on the element and wait for the new text to appear on the same element

Comment: if element doesn't has that string then text will fail with timeout

Comment: And how would i go about comparing the before and after?

Comment: Just add wait for element not to contains that old text , and contains the new text